# Split a data into a length and also by delimiter in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

I need to split the string based on the below Rules

Rule 1: Split string of length 10 char.

Rule 2: If length of the splitted string is greater than 10, then split that string by last delimiter (,) if the value fall greater than length of 10 characters

```
Input 
Row1 - 01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12
Output
Row1 - 01,234,
Row2 - 456890,12,
Row3 - 3456,
Row4 - 7890123,12
```

I tried by this query but it split by 10 character

```
SELECT distinct regexp_replace('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12',
                                '(.{10})', '\1' || CHR(13) || CHR(10)) txt 
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12', 
                         '(.{10})', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried by this query but it split by 10 character                      SELECT distinct regexp_replace('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12','(.{10})', '\1' || CHR(13) || CHR(10)) txt
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12', '(.{10})', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Ok, if oracle can't do assertions, then use this non-assertion one.
*Note - the alternation order is crucial.*
*Also, effectively, this matches every character in the string.*

`.{1,10}$|.{0,9},|.{1,10}`

Formatted

```
    .{1,10} $           # EOS, take the remaining 10
 |  .{0,9} ,            # Mid string, 10 total, ending with ,
 |  .{1,10}             # Overflow, take any 10
```

---

If oracle *can* do assertions, this regex will do specifically what you state.
`.{1,10}(?:(?=.)(?<=,)|$)|.{1,10}`

Formatted

```
    .{1,10}              # 1 to 10 chars
    (?:
         (?= . )              # If more than 10
         (?<= , )             # require a comma behind
      |                     # or,
         $                    # End of string
    )
 |                     # or,
    .{1,10}              # Overflow default, just get 10 chars
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
01,234,  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 7 , len 10 ) 
456890,12,  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 17 , len 5 ) 
3456,  
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 22 , len 10 ) 
7890123,12
```

Comment: What do you mean:  "If Oracle can do assertions"?

Comment: I meant _if Oracle can do assertions_

Comment: You mean _if Oracle can do regular expression assertions_?

Comment: so... can *Oracle do regular expression assertions?*

Comment: I tried using the assertions expression                                                    SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12','(.{1,10}(?:(?=.)(?<=,)|$)|.{1,10})', '\1' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ) txt
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('01,234,456890,12,3456,7890123,12', '(.{1,10}(?:(?=.)(?<=,)|$)|.{1,10})', 1, LEVEL-1) IS NOT NULL                    OUTPUT                                                                                                     01,234,456
890,12,345
6,7890123,
12

Comment: What is an "assertion"?

Comment: @sdevarap  - Posted one without assertions, just in case oracle can't do assertions.

Comment: Thanks Sin, it works fine. Small change if it continue to next line then start with 11 and every line should end as '-' is it continues the output is   01,234,-
11,456890,-
11,12,3456,-
11,7890123,-
11,12

Comment: @sdevarap - Elaborate on that, don't have enough info. It's probably better to open a new question for anything further.

Comment: I created a new question